# Java Robot does not work correctly after a while

Tags: java

I wrote a program which should simulate writing with the keyboard.
I used the java robot for that.
To write it more than one time I put it into a for loop
100 times are OK
But when I do it 1000 times at the end the robot writes not the set text anymore

Here is the code for it

```
package robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;

public class keyrobot {
    private static Robot robot;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
         robot= new Robot();
         write();
    }
    private static void write() throws AWTException {
        robot.delay(5000); //time for changing the application
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){ //1000 x "asdfasdf"
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        }


    }

}
```

And here the result from my text editor

```
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdffddddddddddddddfsssssssssdff
ffddssf





ddddddddddddffffffffssssssssssdfddddddddssssssaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddd




aa
ffffffffffffaaaaaaaaaaadd
ssssssssssff





sssssssssssfsddsffffffffffffaaaaaaaaaaaddaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddffffffsaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssfdddaassssssssssssdddddddddfffffffffffaa





sfffffffffffsasadddddddddddfddddddddddd




ad
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is some buffer overflow happening. Try adding a delay into the loop:

```
Thread.sleep(1);
```

Might have to test higher values.

Or seeing your code:

```
robot.delay(1);
```

Comment: The Output has changed now; but the problem still there

Comment: Thats why I said: "Might have to test higher values."

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem you have to use

```
robot.delay(10);
```

in loop